# How do I limit search to a folder in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-search

In my Gmail, I want to search a keyword that appears only in a specific folder.

Currently, it displays results from all folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By folder, you mean label right? If you navigate to a label, it should already populate the search bar with the format needed. So if I have a label called "Finances" the search should be

> label:finances and then whatever you're searching for

If it's nested, it will be marked by a dash so if I have a "Bills" folder under that it would be

> label:finances-bills search

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is either go in the label or click on the little arrow on the right hand side of the search box.

[image]

For more info you can read about: [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)